# How do I save my entry with my publication date?

Tags: craft3

please help me figure out how to add my entry to the section with my publication date? Here is my code:

```
$date = 1666064471;

$entry = new Entry();
$entry->sectionId = 10;
$entry->enabled = true;
$entry->postDate = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i", $date);
$entry->title = "Title entry";
$entry->setFieldValues([
      'reviewText' => $info,
]);
$success = Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($entry);
if (!$success) {
      Craft::error('Couldn’t save the entry "'.$entry->title.'"', __METHOD__);
}
```

If I understood correctly, then postDate is the system name of the publication date field. The same as $entry->title or $entry->enabled. postDate in my code is not a field I created.
if you remove this part of the code:

```
$entry->postDate = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i", $date);
```

then everything is fine and the entry is added. But I need the entry added with this code not to have the current date.
Please help me figure out how to make this added entry date not the current one, but the one I specified. I don't want to create a separate field for this at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `postDate` attribute should be set to a `DateTime` instance. You might want to use Craft's [`DateTimeHelper`](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-helpers-datetimehelper.html) class, i.e. something like

```php
$entry->postDate = \craft\helpers\DateTimeHelper::toDateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i", $date));
```

Note that in addition to the date the [`toDateTime()`](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-helpers-datetimehelper.html#public-methods) method takes two additional parameters, `$assumeSystemTimeZone` and `$setToSystemTimeZone`, that you might have to play around with to get the time set correctly if the timestamp isn't UTC initially.

Comment: Thx for example. ))) But i use this code: $date = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", 1666064471); $entry->postDate = new \DateTime($date); Is my decision normal? Or is it better to use your method?